# CSS - only top-left part is showing for image background

Tags: css

I'm trying to put [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3OMH.jpg) image as a background but when I use this [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIVWq.png):

`<body style="background-image: url('./image.jpg');">` ...only the [top-left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWnpu.png) part is showing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
  background-size: cover;
```

You can find documentation about background-size properties [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) :

Answer (score 0):

Try the following background properties

```
body {
background-image: url('./image.jpg');
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `background-size` style to modify how the background image is sized and positioned within the parent. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

```css
body {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3OMH.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 background-size: 100% 100%; /*first value is for width and next for height. If you use only first of them, it will be used as width, and height will be auto*/
```

Or

```
background-size: cover;
```